# Create an inverted triangle depending from input 1 - 9

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class NestedFor 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
        int n; 
        System.out.print("Enter any positive Integer: ");
        n = console.nextInt();


        for(int r = n - 1; r>=0; r--)
        {
           for (int c = 0; c<=r; c++)
                System.out.print(c+1);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to output an inverted perfect triangle from my inverted right triangle, I'm having a hard time with this. Anyone can help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Please show example input/output that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: you need to pad with right number of spaces at left. but the second loop control may need be adjusted.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Triangle
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter any positive Integer: ");
        n = console.nextInt();

        for(int r = n - 1; r>=0; r-=2)
        {
           int m = (n - r - 1) / 2;
           for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
               System.out.print(' ');
           for (int c = 0; c<=r; c++)
                System.out.print(c+1);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```